# How to set up my Mac for Homebrew?

Tags: homebrew

Hello I downloaded Python from Homebrew but my computer seems to be using the pre installed Apple version.

Is there a way to change this so that my computer can use the Homebrew Python instead?

I read something about bash files on here but I can only see the apple stuff in there. There is nothing in there from usr/local/Cellar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because i do not know what you already did and if you installed Homebrew correctly or not i would write out the steps of how you should have done it. I will tell you how to install Homebrew and how to point your package to your path so it locates your python before the Apple python. Also i am assuming you have El Capitan.

1) Download Xcode form App Store if you don't have it.

Steps 2-9 are using Terminal (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal)

2) Install the command line tools

```
xcode-select --install
```

3) Install Homebrew (This will install Homebrew to the root):

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

4) Update brew and check with the doctor to fix any issues:

```
brew update
brew doctor
```

5) Check if you already have a .bash_profile and if not create it.

*a) Check for the .bash_profile*

```
cd $HOME
ls -al
```

If you see .bash_profile on the list skip (b)

*b) Create the bash profile*

```
cd $HOME
touch .bash_profile
```

7) Export the Path to the bash file:

```
cd $HOME
echo export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

8) Install your package, for example:

```
brew install python
```

9) Run the doctor and fix any issues:

```
brew doctor
```

10) Check the Path and make sure that the /usr/local/bin: is before /usr/local/

```
$PATH
```

If during the process you get an error saying that you do not have permission add *sudo* in front of the command and try again.

Hope it helps!